# How can i properly validate multiple models in single action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have controller action, which takes multiple models.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginTest(Respondent respondent, List<db.Educations> educations)
    {
       .......
    }
```

ModelState.IsValid suitable for single model, but how can i validate all of this models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the method

```
TryValidateModel(Object)
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for the complete info. 
thus you could do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginTest(Respondent respondent, List<db.Educations> educations)
{
   foreach(var education in educations)
   {
     if (!TryValidateModel(education))
       return new HttpException("some education was not valid...");
   }
   // if you reach this, all educations where valid...
   // thus more code such as saving can go here :) 
}
```